# Error while running MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, dll, bin

Hi  all i have been developing an MVC application in my remote desktop . which is shared by  my colleague also . but while executing the project im getting the following error . And once i deleted the xxxx.dll in my bin the project get executing but why am i getting the following error frequently

**Error 22  Unable to copy file "obj\Debug\xxxx.dll" to "bin\xxxx.dll". The process cannot access the file 'bin\xxxx.dll' because it is being used by another process.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer thanks all

```
 <system.web>
<hostingEnvironment shadowCopyBinAssemblies="false" />
 </system.web>
```

by changing this to like this i could solve

```
 <system.web>
<hostingEnvironment shadowCopyBinAssemblies="true" />
 </system.web>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you can do is to have a app_offline.htm in the root folder of your site.

A template can be found here: 
http://geekswithblogs.net/Vipin/archive/2012/03/28/app_offline.htm-taking-site-down-for-maintenance.aspx

The reason why I am copying this url is because some say there is a need for a minimum size for the file.